# Swift 2 - Wait until animation finishes inside a loop

Tags: swift

So this solution works perfectly for me
[Wait until animation finishes before moving on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32386296/wait-until-animation-finishes-before-moving-on-swift)

Initially I had 19 objects animated with 19 different functions.

However:
Because the animation for each function is very similar I created one function with the required parameters. Now I loop through an array that contains the required parameters and call the function for each item.
But all the animation happens at once rather than one after the other.
What can I do to get the animation happening one after the other?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    for key in hexagonValues.keys {
        animateLabel(key)
    }
}

    func animateSums(key: String, inout delayBy: Double) {
    let sumText = UILabel()

    for number in hexagonValues[key]! {
        if sumText.text == nil {
            sumText.text = String(number)
        }
        else {
            sumText.text = sumText.text! + "+" + String(number)
        }
        UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: delayBy, options: [ .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
            self.flipAlpha((self.hexagons[number])!, myalpha: 0)
        }) { _ in
            UIView.animateWithDuration(3, delay: delayBy, options: [ .Autoreverse, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {
                self.flipAlpha((self.hexagons[number])!, myalpha: 1)
            }) { _ in

            }
        }
        delayBy = delayBy + 10
    }
    animateTotal(key, sumText: sumText, delayBy: &delayBy)
}
```

Comment: can you add a delay for each animation for the duration of its predecessor

Comment: how about an index value 0 to 18 so you can track which animation to fire next? Perhaps a sample of your code would be help so that we could give more complete answers.

Comment: Your code seems to animate a single view `sumText`, what do you mean by all animations happening at the same time ?

Comment: You could use the completion of the second part of your animation to set a variable, or use a protocol you create to launch the next animation

Comment: Thank you all for trying to assist.

Comment: @Luke So, I've added a delay but it does not make a difference at all.